# Get context used by Qt/QML 5.X in WebAssembly build

Tags: c++, qt, qml, opengl-es-2.0, webassembly

Lately I've been trying to build a **Qt/QML WebAssembly** using **Qt 5.15.2 ( compiled with -opengl es2 )** and **Emscripten** **1.39.7** with **C++** on Windows.

This works as intended. I'm using a simple QML **ApplicationWindow** and it displays
just fine. From this point I assume that if QML is able to draw something, there must be
a **context associated** with it.

The next step for me is to grab the said context used by Qt to draw the QML Scene Graph.
I then proceed to create a simple **QQuickItem** of my own to test that.

From what I gathered from examples all around, I set this item **handleWindowChanged** signal to connect the **beforeSynchronizing** of the new Window in charge of the said item.

Long story short, I think I am now able to query whatever is at hand for the current context, the first thing I try is to get the the current **display**, **context** and **surface** like so :

```
  EGLDisplay display = eglGetCurrentDisplay();
  EGLContext context = eglGetCurrentContext();
  EGLSurface surface = eglGetCurrentSurface (EGL_DRAW);
```

But to no avail, **they all return null pointers**.
I do not know much about Qt WebGL implementation, so at this point I think that perhaps I must query those by other means.

1. **QOpenGLContext**

I stumble upon **QOpenGLContext** which I found can be retrieved from my Window ( **QQuickWindow** ) for instance, so in my custom item :

```
QOpenGLContext* qtcontext = this->window()->openglContext();
qDebug() << "openGlModuleType : " << qtcontext->openGLModuleType();
qDebug() << "openGlModuleHandle : " << qtcontext->openGLModuleHandle();
qDebug() << "shared context openGlModuleHandle ? : " << qtcontext->shareContext()->openGLModuleHandle();
```

Output :

```
openGlModuleType : 1
openGlModuleHandle : 0x0
shared context openGlModuleHandle ? : 0x0
```

From this I gather that the context is of type **QOpenGLContext::LibGLES ( OpenGL ES 2.0 or higher )** but can't retrieve the handle apparently either way ( own or shared one ).

2. **QEGLNativeContext**

Then, I tried another shot at QEGLNativeContext which can be made available by using the
private header ( **QtPlatformHeaders/QEGLNativeContext** ), only to find that **nativeHandle** was also returning a null value :

```
if(qtcontext->nativeHandle() == QVariant()) qDebug() << "null native handle";
QEGLNativeContext qteglcontext = qvariant_cast<QEGLNativeContext>(qtcontext->nativeHandle());
```

3. **Emscripten**

I found out that I can query the WebGL current context by Emscripten too :

```
EMSCRIPTEN_WEBGL_CONTEXT_HANDLE emcontext = emscripten_webgl_get_current_context();
```

**This seems to return a non-null value**, yet I found no way to retrieve the context, display or surface handle from this.

---

My goal here is to retrieve a valid **EGLDisplay**, **EGLContext** and **EGLSurface**.

I am not really familiar with WebGL, OpenGL ES, so I think I must be doing wrong calls or simply missing the point here.

Can someone share their experience on this matter ? Or point me in the right direction ?

That'd be nice.

Have a good day all.